# how to autofill a form with id from a previous form

Tags: laravel

I have a previous form in which i created a user and technician. the data is well filled in the tables of the database. Now the form redirects me to another form in which the technician id is needed. I'm working to make the technician id in the new form auto filled from the previous form. I hope my question is clear and I which you could help me. I put my code and the form I want to be auto-filled.Hope you could help me.

**Model1**

```
public function tarificationtache()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\tarificationtache','technicien_tarificationtache','technicien_id','tarificationtache_id');
}
```

**Model2**

```
public function techniciens()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\technicien','technicien_tarificationtache','tarificationtache_id','technicien_id');

}
```

**technicien.Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{




    $user = new user();
    $user->nom = $request->input('nom');
    $user->prenom = $request->input('prenom');
    $user->tel = $request->input('tel');
    $user->mobil = $request->input('mobil');
    $user->role = $request->input('role');
    $user->email = $request->input('email');
    $user->password = $request->input('password');
    $user->save();

    $technicien = new technicien();
    $technicien->user_id = $user->id;
    $technicien->actif = $request->input('actif');
    $technicien->moyenne_avis = $request->input('moyenne_avis');
    $technicien->save();
    $technicien->zoneintervention()->attach($request->zoneintervention_id);

    $technicien->metier()->attach($request->metier_id);

    return redirect('tarification/create');

}
```

**tarification.controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\tarificationtache;
use App\technicien;
use App\tache;

class TarificationController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
 public function index()
  {
    $Listtache=tache::orderBy('libelle_tache')->get();
    $Listtarification=tarificationtache::all();
    return view('tarification.index',
['tarification'=>$Listtarification]);
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    $techniciens = technicien::orderBy('id','desc')->get();
    $taches = Tache::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
    return view('tarification.create')->with('taches', $taches)->with('techniciens', $techniciens);
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $tarification = new tarificationtache();

    $tarification ->tache_id = $request->input('tache_id');
    $tarification ->Tarif =$request->input('Tarif');
    $tarification->save();
    $tarification->techniciens()->attach($request->technicien_id);
    return redirect('tarification');
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
 public function edit($id)
 {
    $tache=Tache::find($id);
    return view('tache.edit',['libelle_tache'=>$tache],
['Tarif'=>$tache],['metier_id'=>$tache]);
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    $tache =Tache::find($id);
    $tache->delete();

    return redirect('tache');
}
}
```

**View**

```
@extends('Layouts/app')
@section('content')
@if(count($errors))
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
 <ul>
    @foreach($errors ->all() as $message)
     <li>{{$message}}</li>
        @endforeach
 </ul>
</div>
@endif
<div class="container">
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form action=" {{url ('tarification')  }}" method="post">
         {{csrf_field()}}

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="technicien">Technicien</label>
                <select name="technicien_id" id="technicien" class="form-control" >

                        @foreach($techniciens as $techniciens)
                         <option value="{{ $techniciens->id }}">
                            {{$techniciens->id}}
                         </option>
                        @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Tache">Libelle Tache</label>
                <select name="tache_id" id="Tache" class="form-control">

                        @foreach($taches as $tache)
                         <option value="{{ $tache->id }}">
                            {{$tache->libelle_tache}}
                         </option>
                        @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Tarif</label>
                <input type="text"  name ="Tarif" class="form-control"value="{{old('tarif')}}">
            </div>




            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value = "enregistrer" class="form-control btn btn-primary">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>


<script>

@endsection
```

[image]

Comment: so basically technician id is newly created user id?

Comment: no it's not the same id each one its id auto increment but there is a connection between them with user_id

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass that value to the view.

```
$technician_id = $user->id;
return view(‘tarification/create’)->with(‘technician_id’, $technician_id);
```

Now you can use this value in your view.

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="technicien">Technicien</label>
            <input type="text" value={{$technician_id}} >
        </div>
```

Comment: Thank you i got                                                                                         "Use of undefined constant ‘technician_id’ - assumed '‘technician_id’'"

Comment: with(‘technician_id’, $technician_id) make sure that you use same name, 'technician_Id' in both places

Comment: return redirect('tarification/create'); 

have you change the above line as in my answer?

Comment: i changed as you mentioned but i got "Use of undefined constant ‘tarification - assumed '‘tarification'"

Comment: there is no technician->id , change it to technician->user_id

Comment: i did that but nothing changed.

Comment: please see the screenshot i posted

Answer (score 0):

**technicien.controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{




    $user = new user();
    $user->nom = $request->input('nom');
    $user->prenom = $request->input('prenom');
    $user->tel = $request->input('tel');
    $user->mobil = $request->input('mobil');
    $user->role = $request->input('role');
    $user->email = $request->input('email');
    $user->password = $request->input('password');
    $user->save();

    $technicien = new technicien();
    $technicien->user_id = $user->id;
    $technicien->actif = $request->input('actif');
    $technicien->moyenne_avis = $request->input('moyenne_avis');
    $technicien->save();
    $technicien->zoneintervention()->attach($request->zoneintervention_id);

    $technicien_id = $technicien->id;
    return redirect('tarification/create')->with(‘technicien_id’, $technicien_id);


}
```

**tarification.view**

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="technicien">Technicien</label>
                <select name="technicien_id" id="technicien" 
class="form-control" >

                        @foreach($techniciens as $techniciens)
                         <option value="{{ $techniciens->id }}">
                            {{ $technicien_id }}
                         </option>
                        @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
```

Comment: remove this foreach($techniciens as $techniciens). it's not needed because you did'nt pass such thing.

Comment: next time update your question instead of new answer

Comment: "Use of undefined constant ‘tarification’ - assumed '‘tarification’'"

Answer (score 0):

here is my new code i did exactly as you told me

[image]