# How to make a dropdown list suggest only options in relation with a selected value?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

In my form below I have two dropdown lists, the first one to choose "metier" and a second one to choose "tache". When I choose a "metier" I want that the second dropdown list "tache" suggest only options in relation with the already selected "Metier".

[image]

**create.blade.php**

```
@extends('Layouts/app')
@extends('Layouts.master')
@section('content')
@if(count($errors))
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
```

```
 <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
 <ul>
    @foreach($errors ->all() as $message)
     <li>{{$message}}</li>
        @endforeach
 </ul>
</div>
@endif
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <h1>Tarification tache</h1>
        <form action=" {{url ('tarification')  }}" method="post">
         {{csrf_field()}}

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="technicien">Technicien</label>
                <select name="technicien_id" id="technicien" class="form-control" >

                        @foreach($techniciens as $techniciens)
                         <option value="{{ $techniciens->id }}">
                            {{$techniciens->id}}
                         </option>
                        @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
////////////
            {{Form::open(array('url'=>'','files'=>true))}}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="metier">Libelle metier</label>
                <select name="metier" id="metier" class="form-control">

                        @foreach($metiers as $metier)
                         <option value="{{ $metier->id }}">
                            {{$metier->libelle_metier}}
                         </option>
                        @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Tache">Libelle Tache</label>
                <select name="tache" id="Tache" class="form-control">

                        @foreach($taches as $tache)
                         <option value="{{ $tache->id }}">
                            {{$tache->libelle_tache}}
                         </option>
                        @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
            {{Form::close()}}

//////////////
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Tarif</label>
                <input type="text"  name ="Tarif" class="form-control"value="{{old('tarif')}}">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value = "enregistrer" class="form-control btn btn-primary">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>


<script>
    $('#metier').on('change',function(e){
        console.long(e);
        var met_id = e.target.value;

        $.get('/ajax-tac?met_id=' + met_id, function(data){
            $('#tache').empty();
            $.each(data,function(index, tacObj){
                $('#tache').append('<option value="'+tacObj.id+'">'+catObj.libelle_tache+'</option>');
            });

        });

    });
</script>

@endsection
```

**route.php**

```
Route::get('/tarification', 'TarificationController@index');
Route::get('/tarification/create', 'TarificationController@create');
Route::post('/tarification', 'TarificationController@store');
Route::get('/tarification/{id}/edit', 'TarificationController@edit');
Route::put('/tarification/{id}', 'TarificationController@update');
Route::delete('/tarification/{id}', 'TarificationController@destroy');

Route::get('/ajax-metier',function(){
        $met_id = Input::get('met_id');
        $taches = tache::where('metier_id','=', $met_id)->get();
        return Response::json($metiers);
});
```

**controller**

```
public function create()
{
    $techniciens = technicien::orderBy('id','desc')->get();
    $taches = Tache::orderBy('libelle_tache', 'asc')->get();
    $metiers = Metier::all();
    return view('tarification.create')->with('taches', $taches)->with('techniciens', $techniciens)->with('metiers', $metiers);
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $tarification = new tarificationtache();

    $tarification ->tache_id = $request->input('tache_id');
    $tarification ->Tarif =$request->input('Tarif');
    $tarification->save();
    $tarification->techniciens()->attach($request->technicien_id);
    return redirect('home');
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to autofill a form with id from a previous form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48925867/how-to-autofill-a-form-with-id-from-a-previous-form)

Comment: nope i don't think it could be the same thing :-)

Comment: ajax request works, you receive taches?

Answer (score 0):

In balde replace `catObj.libelle_tache` with `tacObj.libelle_tache`

In `route.php` replace `return Response::json($metiers);` with `return Response::json($taches );`

In controller `create()` function `->with('taches', $taches)` to `->with('taches', [])`

and edit `$.get('/ajax-tac?` to `$.get('/ajax-metier?`

[Good example](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/2-selects-have-second-one-change-depending-on-what-is-selected-in-first-one)

Comment: Thank you I tried that. The drop-down list "tache" doesn't show anything anymore.

Comment: Check if ajax request works. Add `console.long(data);` to see if taches are returned

Comment: where should i add this line please ?

Comment: after this `$.get('/ajax-tac?met_id=' + met_id, function(data){`

Comment: and edit `$.get('/ajax-tac?` to `$.get('/ajax-metier?`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165909/discussion-between-vpalade-and-it2704).